# How can I get Sam & Max Hit the Road working on Windows XP?

Tags: backwards-compatibility, windows-xp, sam-and-max-hit-the-road

The kids picked up a copy of Sam & Max Hit the Road, but I can't get it to install. What do I have to do?

Comment: They have good taste :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [ScummVM](http://scummvm.org/), it enables you to play a wide range of adventure games on platforms they were never originally available.

Comment: OK, you guys win. Fastest guns in the west -- I was still typing pretty much this. :)

Answer (score 15):

ScummVM should be able to help you out on any platform, it looks like Sam & Max Hit the Road is compatible

Head over to http://www.scummvm.org/ and once installed search for the article "User Manual/Installing a game for use with ScummVM" on the wiki to help get you started.

Comment: Sam & Max is definitely compatible; have played (and replayed) it multiple times that way. :)

Answer (score 3):

My suggestion would be to install DOSBox, and run it through the emulator. I use DOSBox for several old LucasArts games, and it works a treat.

The compatibility checker shows it should work well: http://www.dosbox.com/comp_list.php?showID=52&letter=S

Here is a good guide for getting DOSBox setup: http://vogons.zetafleet.com/viewtopic.php?t=2502

Comment: For SCUMM games ScummVM will work better than DOSBox, since that's what they were intended for.

Answer (score 3):

As other's have stated ScummVM will do the trick for Sam & Max and any other SCUMM based game.

For more general advice on getting old games working check out [Vogons (Very old games on new systems)](http://vogons.zetafleet.com/)