# How do I get Duke Nukem 3D to run under Windows-XP?

Tags: windows-xp, duke-nukem-3d

I was hoping that the answers to [a previous question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/6/the-kids-bought-a-copy-of-sam-max-hit-the-road-for-pc-how-can-i-get-it-working) would provide a generic solution, but it appears not.

What do I need to do and/or install to get this game working?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'd recommend running it under DOSBox -- it claims complete [compatibility](http://www.dosbox.com/comp_list.php?letter=S&search=duke+nukem+3d&submit=Search) for all the Duke Nukem 3D packs.

"Come get some!"

Answer (score 8):

As the source code (but **not the graphics**) of the Duke Nukem 3D v1.5 was released under the GNU-GPL license, there have been several source ports, of which the most notable currently is the [Duke Nukem 3D: High Resolution Pack](http://hrp.duke4.net/)

Installation is very simple, and basically consists of 3 steps:

1. Ensure you have your original Duke Nukem 3D disk in your cd/dvd drive.
2. Run the Duke Nukem 3D: High Resolution Pack installer by double cliking it.
3. Just follow the onscreen instructions.

In addition this, you can also enable the new high resolution graphics by changing the render mode to 32 bit "video settings" under "options" in the game menu.

**You will need an original Duke Nukem 3D disk to use this method**

Comment: Ooh, I forgot about that option!

Comment: Just a minor note, the High Resolution Pack itself is not the source engine--it uses the EDuke32 engine, which can be found here: http://www.eduke32.com/

Comment: +1 for the good suggestion, but I'm going with DOSBox as the more "general" solution as it applies to other games.